# Getting Genesis Entry Headers Back on Post Tiltes

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I have the below code for a child them run on Genesis. The code removes the Genesis entry header / title on all pages and posts including the post titles on all archive and blog pages. I'd like to add the post titles back to the archive/blog page.

```
//* Remove the entry header markup (requires HTML5 theme support)
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );

//* Remove the entry title (requires HTML5 theme support)
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );

//* Add the entry header markup and entry title before the content on all pages except the front page
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'jw_add_entry_header' );
function jw_add_entry_header()
{
if (is_front_page()) {
return;
}
genesis_entry_header_markup_open();
genesis_do_post_title();
genesis_entry_header_markup_close();
}
```

I've tried adding the following but nothing shows up?

```
if ( ( is_front_page() || is_archive() )) ) {
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly formatted and added so that everyone can read it. Half of your code is off screen, making it impossible to read on smaller screens. Not to be rude, but it is annoying having to reformat older users' code just to read it. Thank you :-)

Comment: Just a note, a blog page is your actual home page, so you should use `is_home()`

Comment: Should have mentioned (maybe) that the home page is static or not a blog page.

Comment: The static front page is **not** your home page, it is a front page like the front page of a book. The blog page is your home page

Comment: Even though I set the home page to be static and not a blog in the "Reading Settings"?

Comment: If you set a static front page, that page does not become your home pages, the page set as blog page become your home page. [Setting a static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Comment: Yup I did that, I think calling the blog page the home page when it's no longer set as the front page is confusing and still not sure about my original question.